# Displaying an image in terminal over ssh

Tags: ssh, display

I have a linux machine which I am accessing via ssh with a MacBook. I wish to be able to view some .png files. I have run ssh with the `-X` option, edited `ssh_config` with these lines:

```
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

When I try running `$display fileName.png` I get the error

```
display: unable to open X server ' @ error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/426.
```

and if i run

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 display fileName.png
```

then it acts as if something is running in the terminal but I can't view the image.

I've also tried opening it with `eog fileName.png` and get the error

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Comment: It is unclear from the question as written, but you did edit `ssh_config` on the machine you want to connect _to_, and use `ssh -X` on the machine you want to connect _from_, right? And you restarted `sshd` after making the configuration changes? And you have X11 installed and open on the MacBook?

Comment: It's important to remember that the X11 forwarding is connecting the display only.  The programs being run need to be installed on the remote machine.  So, it's rather unlikely that `eog fileName.png` is going to work if you are ssh-ed into a Mac.

Comment: The linux is the remote machine and I am ssh-ing with my mac. Installed X11 and seems to be working now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Note: Moreover, the $DISPLAY you obtain using ssh -X is usually not :0 but a value incremented for each ssh -X connection, and starting with  X11DisplayOffset (sshd_config, usually #X11DisplayOffset 10 )

Check it: echo $DISPLAY

Answer (score 7):

You don't have xserver default installed on your OSX, so xclient has nothing to connect with.

"X11 is no longer included with Mac, but X11 server and client libraries are available from the XQuartz project." - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341

Answer (score 3):

The best way to view images in your terminal on a Mac is with iTerm + `imgcat` (part of it's shell utilities). You can actually install `imgcat` on the linux machine and then connect to it with ssh in an iTerm instance and it will display images just fine.

Comment: OMG, this actually works! To install on the server, use https://gist.github.com/wesbos/eac5f93478002312db1f (don't use the first command)

Comment: Note there's also `pip install imgcat` which supports options like `--height` which the non-Mac version of the above doesn't.